# Multiple instances of a levelDB database at the same time

Tags: database, nosql, leveldb

Is there a way to access a levelDB database from several programs? Is there some kind of option to open the dababase as read only?

For now, when opening the same database from to programs I get:

```
/path/to/dir/with/levelDBdatabase/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, LevelDB is designed that way and it doesn't allow more than a single instance of the database to be open. All of the options are for a single process, but if you have multiple threads then you can get a snapshot and iterate over it in read-only mode (allowing other threads to read/write to the underlying database at the same time).

Do you want to achieve a specific behavior? If so, let us know what it is and we might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd might have several instance of a program which search in the same database. A solution I am thinking of is similar to yours, wrapping a class around levelDB that then controls the access to levelDB.

Comment: Yep, sometimes there is just no easy answer. I hope this was helpful!

Comment: well then.. you get the flag and the +1. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

I was able to do this in linux by having each process make a directory of its own (e.g. $HOME/.leveldb/myprogram_myPID) and then do:

```
ln -s -t $HOME/.leveldb/myprogram_myPID /path/to/dir/with/levelDBdatabase/*
rm $HOME/.leveldb/myprogram_myPID/LOCK
touch $HOME/.leveldb/myprogram_myPID/LOCK
```

Then $HOME/.leveldb/myprogram_myPID can be used as a read-only leveldb database and multiple instances of the process can do this at the same time without copying the entire database.

It's probably wise to use a snapshot to access the db after doing this to avoid accidentally writing. Also, remember to delete the new directory when the process ends.

Comment: this helps... but really... "read only / uncommitted" access like this should be built-in to the library.

Answer (score 5):

If you only need **read-only access**, each process can create a **copy of the LevelDB folder**:

`cp -r /path/to/dir/with/levelDBdatabase /path/to/dir/with/levelDBdatabase-copy1`

Then, instead of using the original `levelDBdatabase`, use `levelDBdatabase-copy1`.

When the program is finished, the copy can be deleted safely.

Comment: Or if you're willing to wait, each process can just wait until it gets a lock...quickly do a dump... and then exit.

Comment: Nice idea but I feel this would take a while with my 30Gb database locally.